# Swift Compression: doesn't decompress LZ4 image

Tags: compression, swift4, lz4

I'm trying to decompress an lz4-compressed png image with the Swift Compression package, but the code exits with a zero size.
My code is as follows, and the decompressed file is expected to be 240Kb.

**[UPDATE 2]**
I've stumbled upon this in the Apple's doc:

> The frame is documented here so that you can easily wrap another LZ4
>   encoder/decoder to produce/consume the same data stream if necessary.
>   An LZ4 encoded buffer is a sequence of blocks, each of which begins
>   with a header. There are three possible headers:
>
> A compressed block header consists of the octets 0x62, 0x76, 0x34, and
>   0x31, followed by the size in bytes of the decoded (plaintext) data
>   represented by the block and the size (in bytes) of the encoded data
>   stored in the block. Both size fields are stored as (possibly
>   unaligned) 32-bit little-endian values. The compressed block header is
>   followed immediately by the actual LZ4-encoded data stream.
>
> An end of stream header consists of the octets 0x62, 0x76, 0x34, and
>   0x24 and marks the end of the LZ4 frame. No further data may be
>   written or read beyond this header.

So I added the header and footer accordingly and it works. BUT —there's always a 'but'—, **how can I know "the size in bytes of the decoded (plaintext) data" prior to uncompress?**

**[UPDATE 1]**

I give one LZ4 file for you to test, and code usage for decompressing it from the main bundle.

LZ4 file compressed with the sw "LZ4 command line interface 64-bits v1.8.0, by Yann Collet" widely available on the Internet

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eQ204LJs_xsHRwJ_jUcl1Up9NFo8monO/view?usp=sharing

LZ4 decompression usage

```
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "TestImage300.png", withExtension: "lz4") {
        if let compressed = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            if let decompressed = compressed.lz4Decompress() {
                if let image = UIImage(data: decompressed) {
                    self.sourceImages.append(image)
                    print("Unittest: Decompressed image as \(image)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

LZ4 Data extension code for decompression:

```
import Foundation
import Compression

extension Data {

    func lz4Decompress() -> Data? {
        let destinationBufferSize: size_t = 480000
        let destinationBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: destinationBufferSize)

        let sourceBufferSize = count

        let decompressed = withUnsafeBytes { (sourceBuffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Data? in

            let size = compression_decode_buffer(
                destinationBuffer, destinationBufferSize,
                sourceBuffer, sourceBufferSize,
                nil,    // scratch buffer automatically handled
                COMPRESSION_LZ4
            )

            if size == 0 {
                print("Error ")
                return nil
            }

            print("Original compressed size: \(sourceBufferSize) | Decompressed size: \(size)")

            return Data(bytesNoCopy: destinationBuffer, count: size, deallocator: .free)
        }
        return decompressed
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let intArray: [Int8] =  [-16, 1, 1, 39, 0, 19, 11, -30, 7, 10, 29, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 9, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 17, 14, 6, 0, 2, 2, 0, 18, 14, 7, 0, 65, 0, 0, 0, -51, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 43, 0, 16, 2, 9, 0, -1, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 4, 0, 64, 33, -105, 58, 115, 0, 12, 2, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

        let uintArray = intArray.map { UInt8(bitPattern: $0) }
```

// For Visibility the uintArray unsigned is [240, 1, 1, 39, 0, 19, 11, 226, 7, 10, 29, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96, 9, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 17, 14, 6, 0, 2, 2, 0, 18, 14, 7, 0, 65, 0, 0, 0, 205, 6, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 43, 0, 16, 2, 9, 0, 255, 13, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 10, 4, 0, 64, 33, 151, 58, 115, 0, 12, 2, 0, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

```
        var encodedData = Data.init(bytes:uintArray)

        let decodedCapacity = 205
        let decodedDestinationBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: decodedCapacity)

        let decodedData = encodedData.withUnsafeBytes {
            (encodedSourceBuffer: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) -> Data? in

            let decodedCharCount = compression_decode_buffer(decodedDestinationBuffer,
                                                             decodedCapacity,
                                                             encodedSourceBuffer,
                                                             encodedData.count,
                                                             nil,
                                                             COMPRESSION_LZ4_RAW)

            if decodedCharCount == 0 {
                fatalError("Decoding failed.")
            }

            print("Before: \(encodedSourceBuffer) | After: \(decodedCharCount)")

            return Data(bytesNoCopy: decodedDestinationBuffer, count: decodedCharCount, deallocator: .free)

        }
```

You should use COMPRESSION_LZ4_RAW in a case you dont have headers defined in the compression